# Grunt.js not staying in watch mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am sure I am missing something.  I am trying to repurpose a gruntfile that worked on one project into a new project.  The file runs and starts a server instance, but not at the port I have set, and it does not "go into watch mode".

The grunt command results in 
`Opening server for /Users/stevelombardi/Documents/command-central/cc on port 1337.`

And indeed if I open my browser to `http://127.0.0.1:1337` I see the home page.  However, I expected port 9000 (see gruntfile) and for it to watch for changes to my files.

Here is the gruntfile.  What did I mess up here?

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true,
      },
      html: {
        files: [
          '{,*/}*.html'
        ]
      },
      sass: {
        files: ['sass/{,*/}*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:app'],
        options: {
          livereload: false
        }
      },
      js: {
        files: ['scripts/{,*/}*.js']
      },
      css: {
        files: ['css/*.css'],
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      }
    },

    sass: {
      app: {
        options: {
          style: 'compact',
          sourcemap: 'auto'
        },
        files: {
          'css/styles.css': 'sass/styles.scss',

        }
      }
    },

    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: ''
        }
      },
      livepreview: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: ''
        }
      }
    }


});


  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'sass',
    'connect:livepreview',
    'watch'
  ]);
```

};

Comment: try adding   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

Comment: you will probably also need   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

Comment: this is a grunt module that loads all grunt modules automatically: `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` so I do not have to call them separately.  Also, the tasks do not throw an error -- as they would if their modules did not load.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me (modified mine to fit your situation) - i think the "open" will help you:

in my gruntfile.settings.json:

```
"webServer": {
    "port": 9000
}
```

outside of the tasks i have:

```
function mountFolder(connect, dir) {
    path = path || require('path');
    return connect.static(path.resolve(dir));
}
```

then my connect looks like this:

```
connect: {
        livereload: {
            options: {
                port: settings.webServer.port,
                hostname: '*',
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    livereload = livereload || require('connect-livereload');
                    return [
                        livereload(),
                        mountFolder(connect, '.'),
                        expireHeaders
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        web: {
            options: {
                port: settings.webServer.port,
                hostname: '*',
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
},
open: {
    web: {
        path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.web.options.port %>'
    }
}
```

and finally

```
grunt.task.run([
    'web',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open:web',
    'watch'
])
```

Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is perhaps something else is using that port already?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but this Gruntfile works fine now.  I deleted my node_modules folder and package.json, then re-inititalized a new one and installed these modules:

```
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^1.0.0"
}
```

and it works as i expected it to.

Comment: You should delete this question then as it is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: I can't delete a question once it has answers.  I tried.